# Need to convert underscore separated words into human readable form?

Tags: java, regex, string, java-8

I need to convert an underscore separated word like NAME_OF_THINGS to a better readable format like "Name of things" and in few use case I need something like "Name of Things".

I have the below code which I convert using google guava's CaseFormat class. But it doesn't give me the exact expected results. Can someone suggest me a better way to convert this?

```
StringUtils.join(StringUtils.splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase(
                 CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, input)), " ")
```

Input: NAME_OF_THINGS
Expected: Name of things
Actual: Name Of Things

PS: I need something like Name of Things (Of to of) as well

Comment: Since "proper title case" is something culturally variable (e.g. in English we know of should be "of" not "Of" in a title) you may need to use an additional sense-check function of your own.

In your example "Expected" is actually sentence case, because things isn't captitalised.  Sentence case =  Name of things.  Title case (correct) = Name of Things.  Title case (from a cultural agnositc result) = Name Of Things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using java-8 you can do so in a single line :

```
String str = "NAME_OF_THINGS";

Arrays.stream(str.replaceAll("_", " ").toLowerCase().split(" "))
      .map(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1) + " ")
      .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Here we replace all occurences of `_` with `" "` and then convert the entire string to lowercase. Next we split it based on `" "` and then perform sub-string operation to achieve the result.

This gives the output :

> Name Of Things

To get only the first letter capitalized use:

```
String newString = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) + str.substring(1)
                            .replaceAll("_", " ").toLowerCase();
```

This gives :

> Name of things

Comment: "`s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()`" -> `Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0))`. But according to the expected output, only the first word should be capitalized anyway.

Comment: @NicholasK This I can even achieve with the above code which I have shared. But I need something like "Name of things" & "Name of Things". My apologies if my question is not clear

Comment: @NicholasK This solves my primary issue. But I would need something like `Name of Things` as well. Is it possible ? Or I should write a separate function to convert `Of` to `of`

Comment: You will probably need to alter the second code snippet to achieve the result. I'll leave that upto you as an exercise :) *(It should be pretty straight-forward)*  Meanwhile, if the answer helped, please consider upvoting / accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Or this one

```
input.substring(0,1) + input.substring(1).replaceAll("_", " ").toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Pattern`:

```
String result = Pattern.compile("_")
                .splitAsStream(source)
                .map(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

results in:

```
Name Of Things
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want `of` to not be capitalized you can throw in one more `map` function to take care of this:

```
Arrays.stream(str.toLowerCase().split("_"))
      .map(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1) + " ")
      .map(e -> e.equalsIgnoreCase("Of ") ? "of " : e)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or if you want the result to be a `String`:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(str.toLowerCase().split("_"))
      .map(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1))
      .map(e -> e.equalsIgnoreCase("Of") ? "of" : e)
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

***Output:***

```
Name of Things
```

And then if you want to generalize your task a bit more to include more words that should be capitalized ("And", "The", etc), then you can create a `List` of all the words that should be capitalized and do:

```
String newStr = Arrays.stream(str.toLowerCase().split("_"))
      .map(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1))
      .map(e -> notCap.contains(e) ? notCap.get(notCap.indexOf(e)).toLowerCase() : e)
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Where `notCap` is your `List`.